# abstract initialize() method instead of dependency injection, good practice?

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, initialization, abstract-class

This is a simplified example of something I'm currently designing.

```java
public class ExampleManager {

    private Foo foo;
    private ArrayList<Example> examples;
    ...

    public ExampleManager() {
        this.foo = new Foo();
        this.examples = new ArrayList<Example>();
    }

    public void add(Example e) {
        examples.add(e);
    }

    public void doSomethingWithExamples() {
        for (int i = 0; i < examples.size(); i++) {
            examples.get(i).doSomething();
        }
    }
    ...
}

public abstract class Example {
    private Foo foo;

    public Example(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    ...
}
```

In order to use the library, I have to extend the `Example` class and add examples to the ExampleManager, which should be the only class that modifies the `Example` objects.
So I have this `Example1` class:

```java
public class Example1 extends Example {

    public Example1(Foo foo) {
        super(foo);
    }
    ...
}
```

and I currently initialize the manager  like this:

```java
ExampleManager manager = new ExampleManager();
Example1 example1 = new Example1(manager.getFoo());
manager.add(example1);
```

My `Example` needs the `Foo` object, but **I'm wondering if I could get rid of the `Foo` argument in the Example1 constructor**, so if someone uses the library, doesn't have to call `manager.getFoo()` in order to create an Example.
I'm thinking about the following solution, which will hide the `Foo` initialization, so the person who makes use of the library just have to implement the `initialize(Foo)` method, and the `Foo` would be initialized automatically when adding the example to the `ExampleManager`)
In `ExampleManager`: change the `add(Example)` method for:

```java
public void add(Example e) {
    e.initialize(foo);
    examples.add(e);
}
```

In `Example`, initialize(Foo foo); would be an abstract method, so in `Example1` I would have something like this:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

**Is there any better way to do this?**

Comment: I only glanced through... Might the generics be here of any help?

Comment: That looks like simply a different way of implementing dependency injection, not an alternative to it...?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use ANY AVAILABLE FRAMEWORK for DI.

Comment: @Rekin I think generics are not needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have some issues with your OO model in the first place if you need to hand objects around like you describe. - Or maybe your sample code does not reveal the real point of things.

Especially

> `ExampleManager` [...] should be the only class that modifies the Foo objects

and

> `Example` needs the Foo object

look somewhat 'special'.

Can you elaborate what the interactions are between the `ExampleManager` and the `Foo` instance, and between the `Example` and the `Foo` instance?

Ok, with regard to your comment, I propose the observer pattern, much like your `initialize()` approach:

```
public abstract class Example {
    protected Foo callbackHandler;

    public void setCallbackHandler( Foo handler ) {
        this.callbackHandler = handler;
    }

    protected void doCallback( SomeType event ) {
        if ( this.callbackHandler != null ) {
            this.callbackHandler.doYourThing( event );
        }
    }
}
```

and have `ExampleManager` register itself or its `Foo` instance as the callback handler when an object is added to it. Non-abstract subclasses will then only need to call `doCallback(...)` whenever they want to communicate something and won't have to deal with any setup stuff for the callback.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo, I'm going to edit my original post to correct it. The ExampleManager has a Foo instance and a list of Example instances. And it modifies the **Example** objects. The Foo instance is actually an EventDispatcher and I need it inside the Example in order to be able to dispatch events under some conditions. Another option might be making Foo a singleton object, but I don't know if it is a good idea.